# Create persistent RAM storage

Tags: ram, esp32

I am working on an ESP32 device with 16MB of SPI RAM and I would like to set aside some of that space as persistent file storage, kind of like a RAM disk. I will manage the memory/file access myself, so it doesn't need any functionality. I just need to be able to access it and protect it from being wiped during a reset.

Does anyone know how I could go about this to make sure content is not lost upon reset and so that the system allocator is not using the space?

I've been examining memory regions to see if I can figure out an approach but with little luck so far. I also have trouble seeing how the ESP32 is addressing 16MB of memory because the documentation insists that it can address a maximum of 4MB of SPI memory.

I've looked at some of the PlatformIO settings but the documentation on these sections is very… let's just say, I am not sure I understand what options I have.

Any suggestions, pointers or thoughts would be really appreciated because it is important for me to have a persistent solution on the ESP32 that does not require Flash memory or an SD card.

Comment: RAM isn't persistent. Storage (as in disk) is, though. If you need something persistent, you need to look elsewhere. RAM is cleared when the system is shut down, and does not persist afterward. A RAM disk is also cleared when the system is restarted, so it's unclear what *kind of like a RAM disk* means. RAM is volatile.

Comment: We were using persistent RAM disks during the 80s all the time. ;)

As long there is no power loss, it is possible to keep RAM persistent, even during a soft reset. And, no, it is not automatically wiped upon system restart. If it is, it is the OS' doing.

However, considering the many memory configurations in embedded systems and the way memory is addressed, the problem is a little more complex than it was on old 16-bit systems. Still, I am sure there are ways to achieve this.